# How to find out if Bitcoin is running ANYWHERE on my laptop

Tags: client, bitcoind, bitcoin-core

Sooo long story short, I have a Samsung series 7 laptop, i'm running Fedora 18 and I downloaded Bitcoin-qt not too long ago.  I am admittedly stupid for doing so before doing ALL proper research (though I did a lot, but not enough) I am pretty much over my bitcoin phase for the moment and would LOVE LOVE LOVE to completely remove bitcoin and any trace of it from my system.. I have had some pretty big speed issues since installing and even though I have tried to delete bitcoin I am almost positive it is still haunting me and secretly running on my machine....Can someone PLEASE give me the proper instructions to A) Find it on my system and B) DELETE IT ALL!!????
I am soo tired of spending as much time as I have searching Google and every forum under the sun for a simplistic answer...and by simplistic I mean I am also VERY new to Linux based systems so I am not familiar with command lines....
Sorry for being "stupid" for doing what I've done but hey...live and learn!  Thanks in advance for the help!!

Michelline

Comment: Do you have any coins in your wallet?  You wouldn't want to waste those.

Answer (score 1):

By using `ps` and searching for processes named `bitcoin`:

```
ps aux | grep bitcoin | grep -v grep
```

The second grep just filters out the first grep which might under some conditions show up as well.
If you want to kill them just use the following:

```
for i in `ps aux | grep bitcoin | grep -v | awk '{print $2}'` do
  kill $i
done
```

This searches for running bitcoin processes, reduces them to the `pid` field and for each found `pid` it sends a kill.

Comment: so I did what you both recomended and I think bitcoin is GONE!!  thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal window and type in `top`. This will give you a list of all running processes on your system. Use the up/down keys to scroll through it, and look for `bitcoind` or `bitcoin-qt`.

Once you find it, note the process number. Hit `k`, type in that process number, hit enter, type `9`, hit enter. That should kill bitcoin.

Then hit `q` to exit `top`.

Someone else should hopefully be able to help you with the removing bitcoin part.

Comment: That's `htop`. `top` does not have this ability.

Comment: so I did what you both recomended and I think bitcoin is GONE!! thank you!!